# Vue.js mustach not correctly rendered only after indenting root element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, mustache

Does this make sense that in this code the mustache gets rendered plain text:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <p>{{
        myVar
    }}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

and in this code it renders the right way:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{
            myVar
        }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

The only difference is that I've moved the root element.
What also work is when I put it all into a single line:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <p>{{ myVar }}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

> #### So is this an error in the Vue.js renderer or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: This is a very interesting behaviour especially for HTML.

Comment: Looks like a Vue issue in fact, could replicate in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yvxo2ok8kj | You may want to submit an issue in [Vue's GitHub repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues)

Comment: Issue opened - [GitHub vuejs/vue #8103](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8103)